# Cross-Origin Request Blocked - Is this API broken?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pull data from this API with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) http://billboard.modulo.site/.

But I can't get past the [cors](/questions/tagged/cors) error:

> "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://billboard.modulo.site/charts/1995-08-12?max=1. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

From what I gather this is a server side issue with them not allowing cross origin requests, but why would they make an API and not allow people to use it? Is this API just deprecated and unusable now? Am I just doing somethign wrong/using this API wrong? Is there anyway I can make use of this data?

Here's my [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) call for reference:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var apiurl = 'http://billboard.modulo.site/charts/1995-08-12?max=1';
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: apiurl,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(errorMessage) {
      alert("ajax call failed");
    }
  }); // END ajax call
}); // END Document Ready
```

Comment: Why not contact the API maintainer?

Comment: The short answer is that the api is **probably** designed to only work with another server-side service.

Comment: As Jon P said, non HTTP browsers can still consume it, FWIW...

Comment: @jhpratt They don't have any contact information listed

Comment: Or they do not want you to use it. There is nothing you can do other than use a proxy.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks! Going to build a proxy

Comment: Have you tried using CORS Everywhere? Not sure but that resolves a lot of my problems